# Hole in pond liner help

Tags: pond

I had a leak in my waterfall and I finally found it. There is around a 3” hole I found under a flat rock where there is a small falls. It looks like the original landscapers just loaded the hole up with rocks and foam with hopes it would hold. There isn’t enough rubber liner in that area for me to we configure the liner. I have heard patches never really work well. Do I have any options? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: the large rock on the left is shifted down. The hole is below that.]

[image: the year is circled here]

Answer (score 1):

Options are pretty much:

1. Attempt a patch, hope it lasts.
2. Replace the whole liner.

Given that EDPM rubber roofs are routinely patched and seamed in the field, a patch is possible. Having been used for a pond the major impediment will be getting the surface sufficiently clean, and lack of experience. You could *possibly* hire experience, but most rubber roof folks probably won't take the job unless they are having a slow day, and maybe not even then.